# I accidentaly merged two Stack Overflow accounts, what should I do?

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I have two Stack Overflow accounts, because I forgot the password to the first one. Now I remembered the password, but I already had done so much on the second account, that I didn't want to lose it.

I decided to just swap emails, because the first account was using my primary email. To do that I changed the email address on the first one to some temporary one, and then changed the email on the second account to the one I was using on the first.

I don't know how, but these two accounts "merged" and everything is mixed up. Some of my badges are missing, the profile description is different, but for example my reputation stayed the same. What should I do?

EDIT: I just noticed that I can still log in to this account by using the previous email and by clicking the Google (log in with Google) button as well.

Answer (score 23):

There is nothing you can do. We do not unmerge accounts that belong to the same user, and we do not officially support operating multiple accounts. If you do something that gets your accounts merged, then they're merged.

Badges can get reset at a merge, but they'll get re-awarded automatically over the next 24 hours should you still be eligible for them. Otherwise, all of your posts, comments, and thus reputation from both accounts are combined together.

Comment: well explained, I am in process of merging my two accounts, but I didn't get the confirmation email on the original account, so waiting for it...