# I have lost my account and am not getting replies from stack overflow

Tags: support, merge-accounts, duplicate-accounts

What can I do? I suddenly was logged out for some reason (I have been logged in for years and I don't remember my password). When I logged back in my reputation was 1.

This is my account: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5410225/twan

I think both have the same email because when I clicked the dropdown last week it showed I had 723 reputation on SO , now it just says 1 though...

What can I do? I have already sent an email to retrieve my account and a few days later an email to merge my accounts (this one and my real account) but I am not getting a reply.

I am still logged into the correct account on Meta stackexchange for some reason.

If I click on the dropdown there I see 723 SO reputation, but when I click on that I am redirected to SO and see my current account again with just 6 rep...

Comment: There is no SLA for the service desk and they are not a 24/7 shop. Your ticket will be handled in 6 to 8 working days.

Comment: both accounts have different emails, you'll need to provide proof of ownership of both emails in your request somehow

Comment: @SamuelLiew You got a suggestion on how I can do that? Both accouns are used from the same IP. I also got a screenshot that shows me logged in with my reputation but you can just use inspect element to edit a page...

Comment: @user249802 just be patient, once your ticket gets processed the staff will get you to verify them. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18233

Comment: @SamuelLiew Alright, I am still logged in to my old account on meta stackexchange so I hope the staff can see that and merge the accounts.

Comment: @user249802 It might be useful if you provided some proof of mSE ownership too.

Comment: You could edit in an html comment inside your profile description that says you want the account merged to <insert other account here> (do it even for both accounts), if they need more proof that you can access both accounts, that is a way to verify it

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Can you change your current account's email address to the address of your old account? There is precedent for something like that [actually causing an automatic merge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359183/i-accidentaly-merged-two-stack-overflow-accounts-what-should-i-do).

Comment: Thank you. This solved it!

Comment: @twan glad we could help.

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322755/accounts-got-merged-accidentally-or-automatically#comment342792_322761